# How to properly format a time as loaded from a file with numpy.genfromtxt()?

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

my code:

```
def parsetime(v): 
    return np.datetime64( 'filename.txt',
                           datetime.datetime.strptime( v, '%H:%M' )
                           )

hor = np.genfromtxt( 'filename.txt',
                      skip_header = 3,
                      usecols     = ( 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ),
                      converters  = { 1: parsetime }
                      )
```

Got this:

> TypeError: Invalid object for specifying NumPy datetime metadata

Dataset:

```
*****************************************************************************************
 Date__(UT)__HR:MN     Obsrv-lon Obsrv-lat Solar-lon Solar-lat      phi  PAB-LON  PAB-LAT
*****************************************************************************************
 2017-Feb-11 00:00  m    4.87809   1.86737   5.04236   0.27627   1.5995 142.1040  -0.7968
 2017-Feb-11 00:05  m    4.86722   1.86711   5.00023   0.27616   1.5965 142.1233  -0.7972
 2017-Feb-11 00:10  m    4.85641   1.86690   4.95810   0.27604   1.5941 142.1426  -0.7975
 2017-Feb-11 00:11  m    4.85426   1.86686   4.94968   0.27602   1.5937 142.1464  -0.7976
 2017-Feb-11 00:12  m    4.85211   1.86682   4.94125   0.27599   1.5933 142.1503  -0.7977
 2017-Feb-11 00:13  m    4.84997   1.86679   4.93283   0.27597   1.5930 142.1541  -0.7977
 2017-Feb-11 00:14  m    4.84782   1.86676   4.92440   0.27595   1.5926 142.1580  -0.7978
```

Comment: Test your function on a sample date string.

Comment: What's the 'filename' string doing in your function?

Answer (score 1):

### Better define converters-`{}`

`lambda`-s are great for this:

```
converters  = { 1: lambda aPieceOfSTRING: parsetime( aPieceOfSTRING ),
                }
```

as @hpaulj promoted, better solve also the so far present error in the, here only lambdified function, best excluding that at all, as was shown earlier today already [in **your previous**, still un-accepted / un-confirmed, **question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48989034):

```
 converters  = { 1: lambda aS: datetime.datetime.strptime( aS or "23:59", '%H:%M' ),
                 }
```

Comment: How does using this lambda help?  It doesn't add any functionality or correct the problem in `parsetime`.

Comment: The **`lambda`**-constructors are common in defining the `numpy.genfromtxt()` details in `convertors` attribute. You are right in the error, so far present in the `def parsetime( v ):` syntax. Nevertheless, I am almost sure that you cannot be unaware that the very `lambda`-based mechanism of passing the argument and solving also a missing value conversion automation is a `numpy.genfromtxt()` rock-solid standard. Enjoy the day :o) !